# cross-site scripting issues in branch.io

Tags: redirect, xss, branch.io, ios-universal-links

The links I have created in branch.io are redirecting to a porn site insteaf of my app. I asked branch.io directly, as our site is protected, and it seems to happen in branch directly.

This is a sample link
https://z6gvc.app.link/GFIC5VwlA4?%243p=a_facebook&%24deeplink_no_attribution=true

it should redirect to my app, skincoach, but instead it will redirect to a pont site.

I've read branch.io had a vulnerability that allowed XSS back in 2018 but it seems to be back, or never have been fixed.

has anyone experienced something similar with Branch.io links? Any clue on how to avoid the issue or fix it (maybe with other link configuration?)

Answer (score 0):

We were able to locate this issue and have made a quick change on our backend.This appears to have fixed the redirect issue.

Please check from your end and let us know if you need anything else.